# How to map a nested list to a iterable dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, graph, mapping

I have a list of classes and their pre-requisites stored in the paired list:

```
classes = [
    ['Calculus', 'Geometry'],
    ['Trigonometry', 'Algebra'],
    ['Geometry', 'Trigonometry']
]
```

I want to map these classes out to specific indexes to build a graph for the courses using something like:

```
course_index = {
    0: 'Calculus'
    1: 'Geometry' 
    2: 'Trigonometry'
    3: 'Algebra'
}
```

To obtain a new integer map `mapped_classes = [[0,1],[2,3],[1,2]]`

In order to create the `course_index` I created an empty indexed `dict` and added the items from `classes` that weren't present in `course_index`

```
course_index = {key: "" for key in range(4)}

index = 0
for x, y in classes:
    if x not in course_index.values(): 
        course_index[index] = x
        index += 1
    if y not in course_index.values(): 
        course_index[index] = y
        index += 1
```

What I can't figure out is how to map `classes` to their corresponding `course_index` to create `mapped_classes`.

Is there some mapping function that can simplify this process? My attempt to solve this is below, I'm not able to mutate the values in the current class list. It is also very inefficient with the nested loops.

```
for key, val in course_index: 
    for x, y in classes:
        if x = val: 
            x = key
        if y = val: 
            y = key
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invert the course_index dictionary.
Enumerate over classes.

```
invert = {v: k for k, v in course_index.items()}
for i, row in enumerate(classes):
    classes[i][0] = invert[classes[i][0]]
    classes[i][1] = invert[classes[i][1]]
print(classes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
mapped_classes = classes.copy()
for key, val in course_index.items():
    for e, f in enumerate(classes):
        for x in f:
            if x == val:
                mapped_classes[e][mapped_classes[e].index(x)] = key
print(mapped_classes)
```